# Velocity tools backward compatibility?

Tags: java, api, compatibility, velocity

Does anyone knows that [velocity-view-tools : **1.4** version](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/velocity-tools/velocity-tools-view/1.4)(latest version) is compatible with [velocity-generic-tools : **1.1** version](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/velocity-tools/velocity-tools-generic/1.1)(old version)
and [velocity version **1.5**](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.velocity/velocity/1.5)(old version) ?

Answer (score 0):

You would have a better chance also upgrading velocity-generic-tools to 1.4 in your client code, and relying on velocity-generic-tools backward compatibility with itself.

Otherwise, I tend to think that a 1.1 generic tool should work within a 1.4 toolbox, but it must be checked.

finally, since velocity-tools 1.4 rely on velocity-engine 1.5, I don't understand your second question.